# Removing spaces between numbers separated by comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I would like to remove any space between numbers separated by "." or ","

for example: 10 , 45, 3 should be: 10,45,3
and 10 . 45 . 3 should be: 10.45.3

Any help to do that in regular expressions ?

Comment: can't you just remove all spaces?

Comment: Are there more characters than the numbers, spaces, commas and dots?

Comment: in single string s

Comment: just replace space with void string.

Comment: Show more sample input, with and without characters to remove. What are your regular experessions, and in which way were they unsatisfying?

Comment: I cannot replace all spaces, since these numbers are part of long text.

Example text:

Operations and maintenance $258 .277 billion , Military Personnel $153 .531 billion ,Procurement $97, 757 billion.

Research, Development, Testing & Evaluation $63 . 347 billion, Military Construction $8 , 069 billion 
Family Housing $1. 483 billion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `/(\d)\s*([,.])\s*(\d)/g, "$1$2$3"` you should be able to do that

```js
var str = "Operations and maintenance $258 .277 billion , Military Personnel $153 .531 billion ,Procurement $97, 757 billion. Research, Development, Testing & Evaluation $63 . 347 billion, Military Construction $8 , 069 billion Family Housing $1. 483 billion.";
str = str.replace(/(\d)\s*([,.])\s*(\d)/g, "$1$2$3");
console.log(str)
```

Comment: I want to replace the spaces between numbers only. Example text:

Operations and maintenance $258 .277 billion , Military Personnel $153 .531 billion ,Procurement $97, 757 billion.

Research, Development, Testing & Evaluation $63 . 347 billion, Military Construction $8 , 069 billion 
Family Housing $1. 483 billion.

Comment: @ZuhairAli Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful :)