# Remove spaces between digits without gluing separate float numbers together

Tags: r, regex, string, gsub, stringr

In R, I have a vector of strings like this:

```
str_vec <- c("1 9.7 1 0.8", "7.6 7.5", "3.7 13.5", "8.6 1 5.8")
```

I need to remove the spaces within numbers. I.e., I want the first and last strings of this vector to be:

```
"19.7 10.8"
"8.6 15.8"
```

I see there was [another similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43154946/removing-spaces-between-numbers-separated-by-comma) for the java language. That looks useful but I was unable to translate it into R.

Comment: Can you clarify the rules? Why is it `"19.7 10.8"` and not `"19.71 0.8"`? Are the numbers always one decimal precision?

Comment: So what is the code you tried?

Comment: Can you have numbers like `234 5 56.45` that you would like to merge into `234556.45`?

Comment: @Roland Sorry for the lack of clarity. The numbers can have 1-4 digits before the decimal but just one digit after the decimal. And there will be just two numbers in each string. It looks like r.user.05apr's answer addresses the problem perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
library(stringr)
x <- c("1 9.7 1 0.8", "7.6 7.5", "3.7 13.5", "8.6 1 5.8")
str_replace_all(x, "\\d(?:\\s*\\d)*\\.\\d+", function(z) str_replace_all(z, "\\s+", ""))
# => [1] "19.7 10.8" "7.6 7.5"   "3.7 13.5"  "8.6 15.8"
```

See the [R demo online](https://tio.run/##XYzdCsIwDEbv9xShV40/xTJmpwi@SGHUOqVQqqQT5l6@pnrnTXL48p1QKTFcyNFb5olCuhM2M5y24KXQcFAGNOxULzYgjNqDUV3Ftubtj3uONXTcwYZfDDQ@o/Pj4GKUM9@tvcrz0dq8YkIeiveazdsr@Sk8klwQ/sXlK@ZaEwKxKeUD) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zSVJpK/1).

**Regex details**

- `\d` - a digit
- `(?:\s*\d)*` - 0 or more occurrences of 0 or more whitespaces followed with a digit
- `\.` - a dot
- `\d+` - one or more digits.

All whitespaces are removed from each match using a mere `str_replace_all(z, "\\s+", "")`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you are after

```
lapply(
  strsplit(str_vec, split = "(?<=\\.\\d)\\s", perl = TRUE),
  function(x) gsub("\\s", "", x)
)
```

which gives

```
[[1]]
[1] "19.7" "10.8"

[[2]]
[1] "7.6" "7.5"

[[3]]
[1] "3.7"  "13.5"

[[4]]
[1] "8.6"  "15.8"
```

Answer (score 1):

Or:

```
library(stringr)

str_vec <- c("1 9.7 1 0.8", "7.6 7.5", "3.7 13.5", "8.6 1 5.8")

want <- str_remove_all(str_vec, "\\s")
want <- str_replace(want, "(\\d+\\.\\d)(\\d+\\.\\d)", "\\1 \\2")
want
#"19.7 10.8" "7.6 7.5"   "3.7 13.5"  "8.6 15.8"
```

Comment: This is a wrong solution, it won't work with an odd amount of items in the character vector.

Comment: This is working great. If each string has, say, 4 numbers instead of 2, is there an efficient way to write the `str_replace()` line, or would I have to write `(\\d+\\.\\d)` four times?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Could you elaborate? This code seems to be working fine for me.

Comment: @ben See [demo](https://tio.run/##VYxBCsIwEEX3PcWQVYo6GEtNBI8yUGIMUoitTEvF08eJdqGrefz5/3HOqb@w55eeZu6HG9dVJdQtMcB5B0ErAye0YGCPTm1BWTyCxbZgU/Lmy05iAy06KG@rRPP0w1wcRcfxPi6x8ynp1S4bokl6/7VH8iHqkklBE103RCin/mX1GRsgOqyCnN8), the last item is messed up.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah ok, yes. This code would not work if the number of numbers varied from string to string. In my case, fortunately, that is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how exactly this would be acomplished in R, but this is how its done in python

```
import re

regex = r"(\d)\s([\.\d]+)"

test_str = "\"1 9.7 1 0.8\", \"7.6 7.5\", \"3.7 13.5\", \"8.6 1 5.8\""

subst = "$1$2"


result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

Link to [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/LNxH0n/2/)